# How to move the account register fields to the top of the checkout page - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, woocommerce

I've tried searching for the solution to moving the account register fields to the top of the checkout page, however the only solution I have found is by changing the billing template. This would cause issues with updating the WooCommerce plugin.

Is there any way to moving the account register fields to the top of the page using a code to put in functions?

I moved the email field to the top using the following code, is this possible with the account register fields?

```
function bbloomer_move_checkout_email_field( $address_fields ) {
$address_fields['billing_email']['priority'] = 5;
return $address_fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'bbloomer_move_checkout_email_field', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: You need to [override `myaccount/form-login.php` woocommerce template via your active theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)… There is no other way as the fields are hardcoded in the template.

Comment: Would this cause errors when updating the woo-commerce plugin? @LoicTheAztec

Comment: Just read the documentation link of my comment… Woocommerce templates are made to be overridden through the active child theme or active theme. Now you can cause errors if you don't do it in the right way.